# How to copy objects from s3 to redshift in java

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy multiple tar.gz files, which have been split up from a big file. E.g testfile.txt.1.tar.gz, testfile.txt.2.tar.gz to redshift from s3 written in JAVA. 
any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**To Load Redshift from S3**

You need to issue a copy command on Redshift

```
copy testfile
from 's3://mybucket/data/testfile' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
gzip
```

See more information on that [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#r_COPY-syntax)

**To Unload from Redshift to S3**

You just need to issue a unload command on Redshift
e.g.

```
unload ('select * from testfile')
to 's3://mybucket/tickit/unload/testfile_' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
gzip
maxfilesize 100 mb;
```

See more information on that [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html)

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the response. Do you have working Java examples of these?

Comment: you need to run those commands on redshift. if you want to use a java program to initiate those copy commands see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-in-code.html